# Get all nested urls based on nested tag in JSON

Tags: json, bash, parsing, jq

I have a following Json input in a text file `json.txt`:

```
{
   "files":[
      {
         "id":49894894,
         "list":[
            {
               "name":"one",
               "animal_potato_carrot":{
                  "options":[
                     {
                        "id":4989,
                        "url":"https://example.com/text.txt"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":3994,
                        "url":"https://example.com/randomfile.json"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "name":"two",
               "cat_dog_rabbit":[
                  {
                     "id":4989,
                     "url":"https://example.com/text2.txt"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":3994,
                     "url":"https://example.com/randomfile.json"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"three",
               "animal_potato_carrot":{
                  "options":[
                     {
                        "id":4989,
                        "url":"https://example.com/text3.txt"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":3994,
                        "url":"https://example.com/randomfile.json"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get only the first url in the list of `options` for each `animal_potato_carrot` or `cat_dog_rabbit` nested tag only (note they have different structures)

So my output will be first three urls in those blocks:

```
["https://example.com/text.txt", "https://example.com/text2.txt, "https://example.com/text3.txt"]
```

I tried `jq json.txt -c '.. |."animal_potato_carrot"? | select(. != null)'` but that returns all the things inside the body, not just the FIRST url.

Edit:

these two commands return the urls for `animal_potato_carrot` and `cat_dog_rabbit` separately but is there a way to combine these commands?

```
jq -c '[..|.animal_potato_carrot?|select(. != null)|.options[0].url]' json.txt
```

```
jq -c '[..|.cat_dog_rabbit?|select(. != null)|.[0].url]' json.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate two arrays you can use the `+` operator:

```
jq -c '[..|.animal_potato_carrot?|select(. != null)|.options[0].url] + [..|.cat_dog_rabbit?|select(. != null)|.[0].url]' json.txt
```

Please notice that the order of items in the result is not exactly as you requested, because first all `animal_potato_carrot`-urls are determined and then all `cat_dog_rabbit`-urls.

Combining two filters with `,` may come closest to your needs:

```
jq -c '[..|(.animal_potato_carrot?.options),(.cat_dog_rabbit?)|.[0].url|select(. != null)]' json.txt
```

Comment: sorry, i've made an edit to OP to make the post clearer. I'd like all the first urls (even from the `cat_dog_rabbit` block). Are you able to update your answer?

Comment: I have adjusted the answer. Please check!